# Solving recurrence relation T(n/2) + n substitution method

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I am studying the substitution method to find the asymptotic behavior of a recurrence relation and I was trying to prove that:
$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
1, & n = 1 \\
T(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor) + n & n > 1
\end{cases}
$$
is O(log(n)).

I know that the proof fails, but I do not understand why it fails, I misunderstand the data.

I tried this.
$$
T(n) = T(\frac{n}{2}) + n  \le  c(\log(\frac{n}{2})) + n = c\log(n) - c\log(2) + n = c\log(n) - c + n
$$

Since I'm trying to prove that $c\log(n) - c + n$ = O($\log(n)$), I have to go like this:
$$
c\log(n) - c + n \le c\log(n)
\\
c - n \ge 0
\\
c \ge n
$$

If I am not wrong and my proof succeeded, this result should mean that T(n) = O(log(n)), $\forall c \ge n$, so T(n) should have a logarithmic complexity but only for all the c that are greater or equal than n.
But all the proof, should fail and I don't understand why, where am I wrong?

Comment: What is $T(3)$?

Comment: Wait, what do you mean?
Are you asking me to unroll the recurrence for $n = 3$?

Comment: Yes please do. If I understand correctly the formula does not give values for $n=3$. It only gives values for $2,4,8,\ldots$.

Comment: I do not understand, the recurrence gives a value for $n=3$. Well, I guess that the value should be floored or ceiled on the division by two, but it's not the point of the proof. Surely, this recurrence is correct because is the related recurrence of the mergesort algorithm and I asked a demonstration using the substitution method, not by unrolling the relation.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to say a recurrence is "correct". You should include the floor or ceiling so the sequence is defined for all indices. The current question is poorly defined.

Comment: I mean that this recurrence is well know.
I am sorry, I know that correct isn't the proper term.
I should have included the floor or the ceiling, but this isn't the point of my question, because I ask for confirmation about what I have done using substitution method and not by the iteration method.
My fault, I will be more clear next time.

Comment: You can edit the question using the edit button at the bottom of the question. See **Share     Cite     Edit     Follow     Close**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(n)=O(\log(n))$ is not a statement about any particular $n$, but how the function $T(n)$ grows in the long term.

The condition $c\ge n$ forces $c$ grows with $n$, therefore it goes to infinity as $n$ gets large, hence $c$ cannot be a fixed constant, and $T(n)\le c \log(n)$ implies $T(n)=O(\log(n))$ only when $c$ is a constant.

Indeed, from $T(n) = \text{blah} + n \ge n$, you can easily see that it cannot be bounded by any $c\log(n)$ for a fixed $c$ (may be large, but doesn't grow as $n$ grows).

One way to solve this is to see that the total work is equal to $n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \cdots \le n \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} = 2n$. Hence $T(n)\le 2n$ which can also easily be proved by induction (here $2$ is a constant that's independent of $n$.)

Now since $T(n)\ge n$ and $T(n)\le 2n$, we actually have $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.

Comment: All right, this is very helpful.
So, to be clear, at the end of every proof i should have the constant "c" do be some fixed value.
I mean, "c" has to be independent from n, right?

Comment: Exactly. I modified my answer to show the correct solution.

Comment: @Justauser Actually if you go according to the relation actually defined , you will see that $$T(n) = \begin{cases} 1 &, n=1 \\  2(n - 1) &, n = 2^m \\ \text{undefined} &, \text{o.w.} \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Kaind, thanks.  The correct formulation should be something like $T(n) = T(\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil) + n$ (or floor depending on the algorithm), but the method I have used is still valid. It's a bit silly to worry about this in algorithm analysis though.

Comment: Yes, I have already solved this, but just out of curiosity, I tried to prove that his upper bound was logarithmic and I didn't understand why the proof failed:
I guess, I have to study more.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ and $g$ be non-negative functions.

Then $f = O(g)$ if $\exists N > 0, K>0$ s.t. $n \geq N \Rightarrow f(n) \le K\cdot g(n)$.

So you can't say something like $c \log n - c + n = O(\log n)$ for $n \le c$, as what is the N value you will give for this?

Comment: I see. Thank you, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This bit here:

> $$
> T(n) = T(\frac{n}{2}) + n  \le  c(\log(\frac{n}{2})) + n  
> $$

It looks like you are assuming some bound on $T(n)$ with the second inequality. You cannot assume such a bound as this is what you are trying to prove in the first place.

Comment: All right, I understand.
How I could write that down to be more clear and correct?

Comment: @Francesco I don't even understand what this line is trying to say.