# Solving recurrence relation $T(n) = T(n - 1) + n^2$ using mathematical induction.

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I am trying to solve a recurrence using the induction principle (I am asking for help/confirmation about this solving method, so don't answer with a solution developed by iteration method or something else).
I want to precise that I have just started studying recurrence relations, so I am asking for confirmation of my work.

Given:
$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 1
\\
T(n - 1) + n^2 & n \gt 1
\end{cases}
$$
I want to prove by induction, that $T(n) = O(n^3)$.

I have to check if the inequality is verified for T(1):
$$T(1) = (1 - 1)^3 + 1^2 = 1$$

then I assume that $\forall m < n, \space \exists c > 0, n_0 \ni \forall n > 0,\space T(n) \le cn^3$ and I have to prove that it holds for n:
$$
T(n) = T(n \space - \space 1) + n^2 \space \le \space c(n - 1)^3 + n^2 \space = \space cn^3 - 3cn^2 + 3cn - c + n^2 \space \le \space cn^3
$$

Now, I have to check for what values of c, the inequality is verified.
$$
cn^3 - 3cn^2 + 3cn - c + n^2 \le cn^3\\
3cn^2 - 3cn + c - n^2 \ge 0\\
$$

from now on, this is the part about I am not sure if I did it right:
$$
n(3cn - 3c - n) \ge -c\\
3cn - 3c - n \ge -\frac{c}{n}\\
n - 3c \ge -\frac{3c^2 - c}{n}\\
n \ge\ -\frac{3c^2 - c}{n} + 3c
$$
Now, I am not sure if i did that right.
I know that this recurrence is a $O(n^3)$ and it can be proven by expand it, but I want to know if my proof, using the induction principle, is true.
I want to say that this isn't a homework or something like that, it's a simple exercise that came up to my mind.

Comment: For the inequality $3cn^2-3cn+c-n^2\ge0$, as you mentioned you want to solve $c$, that would be

$$c\ge \frac{n^2}{3n^2-3n+1}$$

Comment: @peterwhy but wouldn't be an error?
This would mean that c grows with n, but c is a constant, don't grows.

Comment: $c$ is a positive number that you can choose, so for example, by choosing $c=1$, whatever $n\ge1$ is,

$$\frac{n^2}{3n^2-3n+1} = \frac{3n^2-3n+1 -2n^2+3n-1}{3n^2-3n+1} = 1 - \frac{(2n-1)(n-1)}{3n^2-3n+1}\le 1$$

Comment: @peterwhy Mh, I'm confused.
You should take a look at this other question I made : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4465509/solving-recurrence-relation-tn-2-n-substitution-method
Now, how $c \le \frac{n^2}{3n^2 - 3n + 1}$ is correct and the inequality in the question of the link is wrong?

Comment: In your linked question, for $n$ that is a power of $2$,

$$T(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + \ldots + 1 = 2n-1$$

which is $O(n)$ not $O(\log n)$. So your induction step there would not work. Your induction step actually proved that whatever $c$ you choose, the inequality $c\le n$ will eventually be false for large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the following? $$\frac{T(n)}{n^{3}}\leq 2$$ by induction. $\frac{T(1)}{1}=1\leq 2$. Assume now $$\frac{T(n-1)}{(n-1)^{3}}\leq 2.$$ Then $$\frac{T(n)}{n^{3}}=\frac{T(n-1)+n^{2}}{n^3}=\frac{T(n-1)}{(n-1)^3}.\frac{(n-1)^3}{n^3}+\frac{n^2}{n^3}\leq \frac{2(n-1)^3+n^2}{n^3}.$$ The latter is $\le 2$ since $2(n-1)^3+n^2\, \leq 2n^3$ is equivalent to $5n^2-6n+2  \geq 0$, which is obvious!

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations.

Comment: I am very surprised that someone gave a negative vote for this crystal clear proof by induction of the question asked! Read please before you vote!